# Queue exception handling

Tags: java, exception, queue

This my code for a circularly linked array based queue.

```
public class ArrayQueue{
    private Object[] theArray;
    private int currentSize;
    private int front;
    private int rear;
    static final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY=10;
    public  ArrayQueue(){
        theArray=new Object[DEFAULT_CAPACITY];
        makeEmpty();    
    }
    public void makeEmpty(){
        currentSize=0;
        rear=-1;
        front=0;
    }

public void enqueue(Object x) throws OverFlow{
    if (isFull())
        throw new OverFlow("Array size exceeded");
    else{
        rear=increment(rear);
        theArray[rear]=x;
        currentSize++;
        }
    }

public Object dequeue()throws UnderFlow{
    if (isEmpty())
        throw new UnderFlow("Empty array");
    else{
        Object returnValue=theArray[front];
        theArray[front]=null;//check if this has to be done
        front=increment(front);
        currentSize--;
        return returnValue;
    }
}

public object getFront() throws UnderFlow{
    if (isEmpty())
        throw new UnderFlow("Empty array");
    else
        return theArray[front];

}

public boolean isEmpty(){
    if (currentSize==0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

public boolean isFull(){
    if (currentSize==theArray.length)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

public int increment(int x){
    if (x+1==currentSize)
        x=0;
    else
        x++;
    return x; 
    }
```

}

When I compiled this I get errors as cannot find symbol throw new OverFlow.
How to get rid of this issue.

Comment: Can you show us the code for the `OverFlow` class?

Comment: Did you import the `OverFlow` class?

Comment: No.I don't know much about exceptions.Do I have to have a OverFlow class?Can you please tell  me what I should include in it